# how can i stretch a video in VideoView - Android

Tags: screen, fullscreen, android-videoview, stretch

Every time I show a movie on the screen I see white stripes on the sides. How can I stretch the movie to fit the screen???

Everywhere I see the following code:

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

But it is not stretching the movie, it only stretches the VideoView and I Still see the white stripes on the sides.